# How do I configure Angular2 router with an applciation-wide URL prefix?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I want to serve my application from http://www.domain.tld/apppath/

so that all routes will look like:

- domain.tld/apppath/homepage
- domain.tld/apppath/searchpage
- domain.tld/apppath/resultspage

etc....

**How do I configure the router so that I don't have to explicitly specify the 'apppath' prefix for every single route?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<head>
  <base href="/apppath">
```

or

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/apppath'}],
  ...
})
export class AppModule{}
```

Comment: The second option didn't work for me, but the first one worked perfectly, that is, setting `<base href="/apppath">` in index.html.

Comment: Glad to hear. The 2nd should work as well. `APP_BASE_HREF` only affects the router, perhaps something else is depending on `<base href="...">`